# Auto-fill in Google Sheets stops at blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, autocomplete, vlookup

I'm doing VLOOKUP to merge 2 tables: customer_demographics and transactions, using the customer_id column as primary key.
==VLOOKUP(C2, CustomerDemographic!$1:$4001, 10).

Auto-fill stops at blank cells, and there are over 20,000 rows in the transactions table so it's very time-consuming to have to manually drag it down. There are lots of blanks too. Any help?

I haven't tried anything besides dragging it down manually

Comment: Either use array formula like `=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(C2:4001, CustomerDemographic!$1:$4001, 10))`, or use `BYROW()` function. Post few sample data as text table.

Comment: I tried the =ArrayFormula, didn't work. Not sure how to use BYROW()

Comment: If you post/share sample data and desired output then we can correct your formula. You may share sample google-sheet link.

Answer (score 1):

Have you erased all the data in that column in order to use some arrayformula?, have in mind that if you had previous formulas in other cells, then it won't work. Try this:

```
=INDEX(XLOOKUP(C2:C,CustomerDemographic!A1:A4001,CustomerDemographic!J1:J4001,,0))
```

Just in case you weren't aware, in your formula you didn't define if it had to be an exact match (put a 0 at the end of the formula), then if CustomerDemographic isn't sorted you may have some mismatches